# Specialize one method in typeclass in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a type where I want to be able to change the behavior of a method based on the typeclass instantiations of internal types.

As an example, consider this:

```hs
class Reduceable a where
    reduce :: a -> a
    -- Other methods not relevant here

instance Reduceable [[a]] where
    -- Reduce a list by dropping empty lists in the front
    reduce = dropWhile null
    -- Other methods implemented

instance Reduceable [a] => Reduceable [[a]] where
    -- Reduce a list of reduceable things by dropping empty lists in the front
    -- and also reducing the elements of the list
    reduce = dropWhile null . map reduce
    -- Other methods identical to Reduceable [[a]]
```

In this case, I could use OverlappingInstances to make this code work. However, the other functions are somewhat involved in their implementation and do not change based on the type, and so I'd rather not have to implement them multiple times (which, by my understanding of overlapping instances, would be required).

Is there a way I can get what I want in Haskell?

Comment: But `dropWhile null` doesn't have the right type...? It's an `[[a]] -> [[a]]`, not an `[a] -> [a]`. This is not just a nitpick; I think it's fundamental, in that fixing it will reveal you don't actually want both instances, but only the latter.

Comment: Yeah, I did mess up some of the type signatures. I've corrected them and I don't see what you're getting at with your second sentence.

Answer (score 6):

In general, there's not a really great way to do what you ask. The slightly verbose but idiomatic way is to use `newtype` to select between multiple instances when such exist. For example, you could wrap your elements in a `newtype` for which `reduce` does no work:

```
newtype Don'tReduce a = Don'tReduce a
instance Reduceable (Don'tReduce a) where reduce = id
```

Now your `instance Reduceable a => Reduceable [a]` instance can be made to "bottom out" by converting its elements to `[Don'tReduce a]`s before calling `reduce`. This also gives you some flexibility about where you consider the bottom to be; for example, these may all behave differently, and any one of them may be reasonable in a specific situation:

```
reduce :: Reduceable a => [[[[a]]]] -> [[[[a]]]]
reduce :: [[[[Don'tReduce a]]]] -> [[[[Don'tReduce a]]]]
reduce :: [[[Don'tReduce [a]]]] -> [[[Don'tReduce [a]]]]
reduce :: [[Don'tReduce [[a]]]] -> [[Don'tReduce [[a]]]]
reduce :: [Don'tReduce [[[a]]]] -> [Don'tReduce [[[a]]]]
reduce :: Don'tReduce [[[[a]]]] -> Don'tReduce [[[[a]]]]
```

You can use [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.8.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:coerce) to make conversion between `[[[[a]]]]` and any of the above variation types cheap (free, with optimizations on) at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The first instance for `Reducable` can be written as:

```
instance Reduceable [[a]] where
    reduce = dropWhile null . map id
```

And the second one is:

```
instance Reduceable [a] => Reduceable [[a]] where
    reduce = dropWhile null . map reduce
```

So, `reduce` is of the form:

```
reduce = dropWhile null . map reduceElem
```

where `reduceElem :: [a] -> [a]` can either be `id` or `reduce`.

So let's give `reduceElem` its own class.

```
class ReducableElem a where
    reduceElem :: [a] -> [a]
    
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} ReducableElem [a] where
    reduceElem = reduce

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} ReducableElem a where
    reduceElem = id
```

And then we only need one instance for `Reducable`.

```
instance ReducableElem a => Reducable [[a]] where
    reduce = dropWhile null . map reduceElem
```

Testing it out:

```
λ> reduce [[],[],[1,2],[3,4]] :: [[Int]]    
[[1,2],[3,4]]

λ> reduce [[],[],[[],[1,2]],[[3,4],[5,6]]] :: [[[Int]]]
[[[1,2]],[[3,4],[5,6]]]
```